# Making write to a file thread safe

Tags: ruby, file-io, thread-safety

I have a function in a ruby file that writes to a file like this

```
File.open("myfile", 'a') { |f| f.puts("#{sometext}") }
```

This function is called in different threads, making file write such as the above not thread safe. Does anyone have any idea how to make this file write thread safe in the simplest way?

More Info: If it matters, I am using the rspec framework.

Answer (score 12):

You could give a lock by **[File#flock](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-i-flock)**

```
File.open("myfile", 'a') { |f| 
  f.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
  f.puts("#{sometext}") 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Referring to: http://blog.douglasfshearer.com/post/17547062422/threadsafe-file-consistency-in-ruby

```
def lock(path)
  # We need to check the file exists before we lock it.
  if File.exist?(path)
    File.open(path).flock(File::LOCK_EX)
  end

  # Carry out the operations.
  yield

  # Unlock the file.
  File.open(path).flock(File::LOCK_UN)
end

lock("myfile") do
  File.open("myfile", 'a') { |f| f.puts("#{sometext}") }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple logger I wrote:

```
require 'fileutils'

module DebugTools
  class Logger
    def self.log(message)
      FileUtils.touch(path) unless File.exist?(path)

      lock(path) do |file|
        file.puts(message)
      end
    end

    def self.lock(path, &block)
      File.open(path, 'a') do | file |
        file.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
        block.call(file)
        file.flock(File::LOCK_UN)
      end
    end

    def self.path
      "#{Rails.root}/log/debugtools.log"
    end
  end
end
```